# Android Beam: Is there any callback or error code if receiver is not authorised

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I am developing an Android application which uses Beam to send custom message to another device.

If my application is present on both the devices then it works fine. But if it is not present at the receiver end then still at the sender I get onNdefPushComplete() success callback.

I am wondering if there is any result code or callback which tell that it has been delivered to default application or may be some contraint that might cause the message to only get delivered to authorised application(in this case the same application).

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The call to onNdefPushComplete() only tells you that the (low-level) NFC peer-to-peer data transfer was successful. It does not provide any information about which app the data has been delivered to. On Android, the way to force data to be delivered to a particular app, would be to add an Android Application Record. However, this can still be overridden on the receiving device by an app that is running in the foreground and has activated NFC foreground dispatching (forcing all NFC intents to be delivered to that app as long as it is in the foreground).

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I am working on Fund transfer kind of crucial application. That's why I needed the callback for message not received by application. But thanks for the reply!